# Yii2 merge queries like cdbcriteria in yii1

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have a problem regarding merge of multiple queries.
In Yii 1.x you could merge a CDbCriteria with

```
$criteria->merge($otherCriteria)
```

How can I achieve the same nested conditions etc with queries in Yii2?

**Edit:** 
Let's say I want separate queries to form subqueries. And after all subqueries are done I want to merge them together to the one big query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `CDbCriteria` concept in `Yii2` anymore. Instead you can refer to the following classes:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html (**yii\db\Query**)
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html (**yii\db\ActiveQuery**)

All you did before with `CDbCriteria` now you can do with above classes. So, there will be no need to merge two criteria with each other.

**update**

`Yii2` also supports sub-queries like below (as `Yii2`'s official guide):

```
$subQuery = (new Query)->select('COUNT(*)')->from('user');
$query = (new Query)->select(['id', 'count' => $subQuery])->from('post');
```

Which results in:

```
SELECT `id`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user`) AS `count` FROM `post`
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#building-query

Comment: I know there is no CDbCriteria in Yii2. It's more how can I merge multiple queries if I have some (because subqueries etc). Or do I have to create only 1 big query now?

Answer (score 4):

I also recently ran into this issue. Complete fusion of queries (select, join etc.) does not exist (as I understand it). But you can manually merge conditions, for example:

```php
    $query1 = \app\models\User::find()
        ->where(['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2']);

    $query2 = \app\models\User::find()
        ->where(['and', '[[column3]] = :column3', '[[column4]] = :column4'])
        ->addParams([
            ':column3' => 'value3',
            ':column4' => 'value4'
        ]);

    // merge conditions
    $query1->orWhere($query2->where);
    $query1->addParams($query2->params);

    // build SQL
    echo $query1->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

Built SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `yii2_user` WHERE 
    ((`column1`='value1') AND (`column2`='value2')) OR 
    ((`column3` = 'value3') AND (`column4` = 'value4'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to both the excellent answers above, should you need to merge two conditions to send on to a method which takes a 'condition' parameter in the same format as `where()`, then you can either build your own array:

```php
$condition1 = ['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2'];
$condition2 = ['column3' => 'value3', 'column4' => 'value4'];
$condition = [
    'or',
    $condition1,
    $condition2,
];
$model->updateAll([ 'column5' => 'value5' ], $condition);
```

Or, if it feels more logical, you can use a temporary query object to build the conditions up and merge, etc. Then pass the generated where condition from it, e.g.:

```php
$query1 = new \yii\db\Query;
$query1->andWhere(['column1' => 'value1', 'column2' => 'value2']);
$query2 = new \yii\db\Query;
$query2->andWhere(['column3' => 'value3', 'column4' => 'value4']);
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
$query->where($query1->where)
      ->orWhere($query2->where);

$model->updateAll([ 'column5' => 'value5' ], $query->where);
```

Obviously, this makes more sense when the queries or conditions are built up elsewhere in the code and separately passed the the place where the model method is executed.