# confusion in using Yii 2 query bulider andWhere , orWhere?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I am using yii 2, I have written query to get records from table using andWhere and orWhere but result is confusing. Let me show you what problem I am facing.
my query is

```
Mission::find()->where(['IN', 'id', $ids])->orWhere(['created_by' => $user->id])->activeOrCancel()->all()
```

active or cancel() is defined in model

```
public function activeOrCancel()
{
    $this->andWhere(['status' => '1']);
    $this->orWhere(['status' => 'cancel']);
    return $this;
}
```

when i debug and checked the sql query. I got this in result:-

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_mission` WHERE (((0=1) OR (`created_by`=75)) AND (`status`='1')) OR (`status`='cancel')
```

**How can I get this type of result**

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_mission` WHERE ((0=1) OR (`created_by`=75)) AND ((`status`='1') OR (`status`='cancel'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `activeOrCancel()` condition can be written as follows:

```
status IN ('1', 'cancel')
```

As such you can rewrite your `activeOrCancel` function for this:

```
public function activeOrCancel()
{
    $this->andWhere(['status' => ['1', 'cancel']]);
    return $this;
}
```

In addition you can rewrite the first condition as:

```
->where(['or', 'id' => $ids, 'created_by' => $user->id])
```

Thus combining the two:

```
Mission::find()
    ->where((new Query())->where(['or', 'id' => $ids, 'created_by' => $user->id])->where)
    ->activeOrCancel()
    ->all();
```

Comment: I will try this on monday. let's see it works for me. I have one more function which I didnot mention here. notDeleted() this will be also added in my query. The sql query which yii generates is creating problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use intermediate query objects to group conditions.
For example:

```
$queryPart1 = (new Query)
    ->andWhere(['IN', 'id', $ids])
    ->orWhere(['created_by' => $user->id]);

$queryPart2 = Mission::find()
    ->activeOrCancel();

$result = Mission::find()
    ->andWhere($queryPart1->where)
    ->andWhere($queryPart2->where)
    ->all();
```

**Note**: this is simple case (without query params).
More about merging queries: [Yii2 merge queries like cdbcriteria in yii1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177329/yii2-merge-queries-like-cdbcriteria-in-yii1/28371428#28371428)